# Custom 3.5mm front audio jacks? Win10, 9-pin MB audio connector

Tags: audio, motherboard

Not sure if this is the right forum; if not, please feel free to gently redirect me to a more appropriate place to ask this question.

I'm not an audiophile, this would mostly be for conference call audio on my personal desktop PC (Win10). I *do* need 'hotswapping', where if I plug in headphones, any other speakers or microphones on the system are disabled (and when the headphones are unplugged, it goes back to the previous input/output). I think my MB does this automatically with the rear panel audio ports, but those are not easily accessible (large heavy PC case, jammed behind a desk).

I looked at aftermarket PC front bays with audio ports, but don't have an open bay so I'm avoiding this option. I thought I could just buy a few jacks and install them directly on the front of my case and wire them to the MB 9-pin audio connector (not afraid of a soldering iron). Then I started Googling, and got lost.

I previously thought that the ability to sense presence of a plug (and hot-switch outputs) was based on resistance in the actual audio/ground loop, but instead maybe that requires switched jacks? I got lost on what type of jack I'd need (how many switches, if any). So, I'm posting here for feedback before buying parts - to see if this project even makes sense, and if so, what I need to look for in the jack specs.

I'd want to be able to use either my regular cell phone headset (integrated mic, one plug, 4 connectors, 3.5mm) or one of my other (better?) PC headsets that actually split the audio and mic into two different 3.5mm plugs, which is why I've added a splitter below.

1. MB has a 9 pin audio connector (MSI x99A SLI Plus)
2. Buy a 9-pin audio extender cable that will reach the front of my case (40cm)
3. Buy a 9-pin splitter cable (10cm)
4. Connect one side to a 3.5mm 4-conductor jack (TRRS?)
5. Connect the other side to two separate 3.5mm 3-conductor jacks (2x TRS? one mic, one audio)
6. drill three holes and install the three 3.5mm jacks into the case front, and label them

So, the key questions are (a) how likely am I to end up with hot-swap issues if I'm feeding off the MB 9-pin connector, (b) if this seems workable, what specs should I be looking for when buying the jacks, and (c) if this /does/ involve switched jacks, is connecting up 3 different jacks going to get so complicated that an average Joe is going to screw it up somehow?

This all assumes that the MB Drivers will play nice with anything connected to the 9-pin MB port...

Thank you!!